# total commander masks path variable

Tags: java, path

I have all java variables added. When I try to run cmd from within totalCommander and type "path" I get this message:
    **PATH=nvInitDll; App c:\totalcmd.exe - redirect success.**

But when I try and run command line by cmd.exe and type "path", everything is neat and right as it is specified, i.e the commands prints all paths as was specified in system variables. What's the problem, guys? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: When you say *run cmd from within totalCommander* you are entering "cmd" in the "commandline of TC? How exactly do you do that?

Comment: I use a command "Commands->Run DOS" from the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely driver problem. Try installing your latest graphic card drivers. Please provide your OS for more detail.

Comment: Windows 7, Ultimate edition, Lenovo B560. I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: Why would the graphics driver influence the path settings used by TotalCommander?

Comment: nvInitDll is relevant to an Nvidia card driver. Thus it must be it that messed up the variable